# SP 2013 - Trying to get items from a list - some say undefined

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 Document Library which has some images stored in a column called "Name".

I am trying to get the URL of the image but it keeps saying "undefined".
I also try to get another column "MyCol" (single line of text) and it says undefined.
I can get other information from the Document Library (such as JobTitle - which is a Single Line of Text)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Further digging has shown me that when I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d.results[result]));
```

It doesn't seem to pull back the MyCol value?

Thanks
P

```
<script>

$.ajax ({
    
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('photos')/items?expand=Name",

    dataType: 'json',

    async: false,

    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },

    success: function(data) {

        var html = '';

        var count = 0;

        for(var result in data.d.results) {


                html+='Name:' + data.d.results[result].Name + '<br>'; //this gives undefined
                html+='MyCol:' + data.d.results[result].MyCol + '<br>'; //this gives undefined
    
                html+='Job Title:' + data.d.results[result].JobTitle + '<br><br>'; //this gets the data from the Document Library

            count++;

 

            if(count >= 6)

            {

                break;

            }

        }

        $('#staffInformation').append(html);

    },

    error: function ajaxError(response){

        console.log(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);

    }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$expand` is used to also grab data from a related item (typically Lookup or user field).

What you want is `$select` to specify columns to return. Use `FileLeafRef` to get the file name (also take a look at `FileRef` or `FileDirRef` :

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('photos')/items?$select=FileLeafRef"
```

Ref: [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests).

As a side note, you can reduce network footprint by changing the headers:

```
"Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
```

The response will only contains the data, not the metadata. Just adjust the returning object property walking (there's no intermediate `d`)